# How do I create a 1/2 and 3/4 cylinder?

Tags: modeling

I don't know how else to state my question. What I'm looking to do seems like it ought to be very simple.

I want to take a brand new torus, and cut it in half. i.e. the exact shape you'd get if you cut a real donut in half (with the sliced edges being a face (I don't care if there are multiple edges / faces).

The same thing, but only cutting out 1/4, i.e. removing the bits of the torus shown in the selected image, and sealing / adding a face to the cut edges.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly:

you may hit the <kbd>P</kbd> and select the **Selection**

It will detach the selection from your main object and create a new independent object.

After that you may select the edges and hit <kbd>F</kbd>

Something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If its not your required result, please try to update the question with more details